# Get count of total media file available in sdcard folder?

Tags: android, cursor, sd-card

How can get total count of available media file in sdcard/some/ folder that should include audio, images, video.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this

```
File file=new File("/sdcard/domedir");
File[] list = file.listFiles();
int count = 0;
for (File f: list){
    String name = f.getName();
    if (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".some media extention"))
       count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write a simple recursive method like this one :

```
public int countFile(String path) {
    int count = 0;
    File f = new File(path);
    if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {

        for (File fi : f.listFiles()) {
            if (fi.isDirectory())
                count += countFile(fi.getAbsolutePath());
            else
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply check whether the type of files correspond to common media types

```
     static class MyDocFileFilter implements FileFilter{
          private final String[] myDocumentExtensions 
                    = new String[] {".java", ".png", ".avi", ".mkv"};

          public boolean accept(File file) {

                  if (!file.isFile())   return false;

                  for (String extension : myDocumentExtensions) {
                         if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension))
                                  return true;
           }
           return false;
    }
}
```

Then use File to list all the required files using the filter. And change extensions accordingly

```
File file = new File("DIRECTORY_NAME");
File[] fileslist = file.listFiles(new MyMediaFileFilter());
```